# Streaming/playing the video from the user's filesystem

Tags: javascript, protocols

The user has a video file on his system. Now, on the webpage there is an option to select a video file from his computer itself. I am seeking a way to directly stream the video on a html5 video tag(or any other player for that matter) from his/her computer on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only need to support Web Browsers that support HTML5 then try

**WebRTC** (http://www.webrtc.org/home)

> WebRTC is a free, open project that enables web browsers with
> Real-Time Communications (RTC) capabilities via simple JavaScript
> APIs. The WebRTC components have been optimized to best serve this
> purpose.

It is important to note that this is just my personal preference.

## Edit:

If you want to steam a file then take a look at VideoLAN (or VideoLAN Server). http://www.videolan.org/index.html

[image]